# Using ArcPy and certificate-based login?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

We have an ArcGIS Server/Portal federation, and I'm trying to publish a map using Server.  The login gauntlet is that Server defers to Portal, which, in turn, defers to a SAML server which checks the certificate presented and makes the go/no-go call.

The certificate needed was imported by the user.

When I run my publish script, it runs a while, then pops up a dialog box that basically says, 'Is this the proper identity certificate?' with enough info to make that determination, with OK/Cancel options.

That's fine for current testing, but not so great for when we want this process to be run in a fully-automated fashion.

So the question is, is there some way, in arcpy, to basically predeclare, 'This file is the certificate you want, present it if challenged'?

Comment: If the certificate needed was imported by the user, it sounds like you're using self-signed certs? Maybe I dont completely understand your workflow, but my take on it is: go the extra mile for domain certs or if possible even signed by a CA. self-signed is nothing but a headache once you start including people other than yourself - especially if they're using non-browsers to authenticate (like python and arcpy).

Comment: There is a self-signed cert involved, but that's a separate issue from what I'm talking about.  And yes, when we get out of testing, we will replace that with a CA-signed cert.  The certificate in question is what the client is using to identify him- or herself.